# How to check if Pass in Passbook is used

Tags: objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5, passbook

I need to use PassBook in one of my applications. I have been successfully creating the passes. I have spent the last two days of mine to study the PassBook documentation but cannot figure out the point that if we want to know whether a pass has been used or not, how shall I be able to do that? Since the passes are independent of the app so I am guessing that our web server should get to know about it. is it possible?

Any direction will be much appreciated!

Farrukh Javeid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well a pass would normally have a barcode, like the ones on a ticket.
Then we the barcode gets scanned your back should invalidate that barcode, now when it gets scanned again it code will show up as invalid.

You can update a pass via Apple's push notification server, tell it that it was been used.

Comment: I might be a little confused here but the application scanning the barcode could not possibly be ours. then how are we supposed to know or our application needs to be invoked then how are we supposed to know.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The party scanning the pass is the one who needs to tell you that the pass is used. There is not other way to do that with a 100% certainty.

Comment: Is there any way we can get the number of times a pass has been read? or restrict a pass to be used only a certain number of times?

Comment: No, there is not way you can do that.

Comment: Well, that will make me one of the mob who will hate PassBook for that.

Comment: I think you are using passbook in the wrong way. It's ment to hold ticket, coupons and membership cards. These will all have a backend to verify that the barcode is valid. thus there should not be a need to only display a pass X times.

Comment: you are right but some coupons are only meant to be used for a number of times?

Comment: Then still the backend system will now how many times a coupon has been used. thus it can only tell if the coupon is valid. You will need some kind of callback from that system that will tell if the coupon is valid. If you could only open the pass X times flick thru the pass would invalidate the pass before you could even use it.

Comment: well, I guess that is the only solution after all.